# Use this script without RequireJs (or any module loader)

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm not a JavaScript developer, and I'm struggling to do a little experiment as a side project.
I'm trying to use this script without [RequireJs](https://requirejs.org/).

https://github.com/xxmuaddib/lottie-colorify/blob/master/examples/example1/index.html

I've been trying for a while and checked StackOverflow, but I have very little knowledge of JavaScript.

Here's what I got so far:

```js
<html style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.6.3/lottie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
   <!--  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="../../lib/umd/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #ccc; margin: 0px; height: 100%; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10px">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #333" id="bodymovin"></div>

    <script>
    //requirejs(['../../lib/umd/index'], function (lc) {"
        $.getJSON('https://assets6.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_guwqiaxe.json', function (data) {
          var animData = {
            wrapper: document.getElementById('bodymovin'),
            animType: 'html',
            loop: true,
            prerender: true,
            autoplay: true,
            animationData: lc.flatten('#ffff00', data),
          };
          var anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);
        });
    //});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I removed the CDN for RequiredJS and its implementation and linked the script manually between `<script>` tags.
But now the variable `lc` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

requirejs load the script for this file
https://github.com/xxmuaddib/lottie-colorify/blob/master/lib/umd/index.js
so if you'll comment this library just remove its callback return "lc" variable
line that throws the error should be like that
animationData: flatten('#ffff00', data), //you already imported the lib/umd/index.js file which has this function

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, maybe the https://github.com/xxmuaddib/lottie-colorify/blob/master/lib/umd/index.js is not exported ? Since I got `flatten is not defined`
It seems from what I understand in the https://github.com/xxmuaddib/lottie-colorify/blob/master/lib/umd/index.js file, that flatten is a method from an object, but I don't understand where is it defined.

Comment: i see it's exported from this file 
https://github.com/xxmuaddib/lottie-colorify/blob/master/lib/index.js
try to import this script instead

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately, it's still not working, I'm getting two errors, the first one is `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined` and the second one is still `ReferenceError: flatten is not defined`
I'm not of any help, but if you find a solution to this problem, I'll for sure buy you a coffee

Comment: :D thanks, i'm really sorry i couldn't help more for this issue